# Using checkboxes with PHP and MySQL- passing 1 and 0 to and from the db

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

So lets say I have a checkbox

```
<input style="margin-left:0px;" type="checkbox" value="1" name="disablePause" class="product-options-cbx" <?= $this->oProduct->getDisablePause() == 1 ? 'checked="checked"' : ''; ?> /> Disable Pause
```

This checkbox will pull a value of 1 or 0 from the database and if it is 1 will load checked.  what happens is when the user deselects the checkbox then submits the form instead of passing 0 to the db it is erroring.  I'm pretty sure my error lies within the value tag.  any suggestions?  Ultimately, I just want to be able to pass 1 or 0 back and forth depending on if box is checked (1) unchecked (0)

Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the value of a checkbox is 0, it doesn't actually send that param to the "receiving" page. If you are using a simple 1 or 0 value then you can just listen for it on your parsing page by using `isset()`

`$disablePause = isset($_REQUEST['disablePause']) ? 1 : 0;`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that an unset check box sends *no data*, not a 0. (That is, an unset checkbox behaves identically to a checkbox that does not exist). You need to use PHP's `isset()` function to test if the checkbox is set:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['disablePause']))
{
    //the checkbox is set
} else {
    //the checkbox is not set
}
?>
```

You do this wherever you check whether the checkbox is set.